# How to embed an XML/XSLT document into an HTML page

Tags: php, html, xslt, embed

I have a Web page created with PHP/CSS3/HTML5/MYSQL which work correctly: The software is able to manage the content, customize the menu and such.
As a separated project, I have a lot of documentation in XML/XSLT format.

I would like to include the documentation into the web content, so the ideal solution should be something like to embed the XML/XSLT document into the web, but I do not know how.

Some possible solutions:

- Include directly the XML into the HTML file: that does not work.
- Parse the XML/XSLT with php and insert it into the HTML: It work but all the job is made in the server side, which is not a very good idea.
- Embed the XML/XSLT into an iframe, but the only way to set the iframe height to the content is with Javascript, which seem an ugly solution.
- Re-write the whole web system with only XSLT, which is totally outside the possibilities of my time-schedule.

What is a good way to embed an XSLT document into an HTML page? There is any better solution?

Short example of an XML documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="documentation.xsl"?>
<document>
    <header-1 title="Introduction">
        <p>Any text into the XML documentation</p>
    </header-1>
</document>
```

A short example of XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
    <xsl:template match="//document">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="header-1">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></h1><xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <span><xsl:apply-templates/></span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A short example of HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header><title>Test</title></header>
    <body>
        Here the XML/XSLT should be included    
    </body>
</html>
```

EDITED:

The solution for parsing the XML/XSLT with PHP:

```
$xsltProc = new xsltProcessor();
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load('documentation.xsl');
$xsltProc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('test.xml');
echo $xsltProc->transformToXML($doc);
```

Comment: I'd parse it with PHP - that's what SimpleXML is for: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php :)

Comment: PHP include a module that allow XSLT directly: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php

Comment: Then why not use it?

Comment: Because it is a load for the server, so I prefer to ask first to know more opinions about this problem. If there is no new ideas, I will probably use PHP or an iframe+javascript

Comment: Have you done any testing? I can't imagine it's that much of a load (unless they're huuuuge files). Parsing it with javascript would probably be worse because you're relying on the browser to handle the load - and it may not - which will give you an unhappy visitor.

Comment: Files are not so huge (5-30 pages), but the server has to manage lot of client request, so in client-server systems it is always better to let's the client do as much as possible. For the client, it is only 0.5s to wait, but for the server 0.5s*N requests may overload it.
I will edit to add the PHP code solution.

Comment: Have you thought about converting them locally into HTML and then including those? if the docs don't change it's silly to parse them each time they're viewed. Think about converting them instead...